# GWT - No WC3 XML DOM Implementation? What are my options?

Tags: xml, gwt, dom

I recently started working with GWT to test it as a possible solution for the next version of our XML editor application.

One thing I realized right away was that the GWT classes for working with XML (like `com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document`) were not WC3 compliant. Mainly they lack methods like `createElementNS`

I understand that they did this for compatibility, but working with namespaces is a must for any serious XML application.

So I decided that I would just extend the GWT class and add the lacking methods. Something like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.impl.DocumentImpl;

public class Document extends DocumentImpl implements com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document {
    public Element createElementNS(String ns, String localName)
    {
         ....SOME JNSI ACTION HERE....
    }

}
```

But apparently `DocumentImpl` is not visible to be used outside its own package, so I am quickly in a situation where I start to have to implement all the DOM methods myself.

I really would prefer not to do this, does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks,

Casey

Answer (score 1):

We've done some extensions by calling out to Javascript and accessing facilities of the underlying Javascript DOM. But you quickly start hitting browser dependencies, and realising that GWT deliberately left out some of these features because they are quite difficult to implement in a way that works cross-browser. They give you the lowest common denominator (by which I mean of course the highest common factor...) for a good reason.

Comment: I understand that, so basically what you are saying is that I shouldn't do this in GWT?